# Downloading images from firebase storage swift 2.2

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-storage

I have a project in which i have a image view (in Xcode 7.3).
I need to show an image from my firebase storage and to my UIImageView, right now i am using this code: 
(but it's really slow - each time i enter the view it takes 3-4 seconds to show my image)

```
func showImage(){

    FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/restaurantproject-27368.appspot.com/o/bestdeal.jpg?alt=media&token=dcbd9da1-d368-48ef-8ed2-a861103e4ab8").dataWithMaxSize(10 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }        
    })
}
```

Is there maybe a better way? 
(plus i need to cache it somehow in my device but i need it to check my image every time i enter the app because i need to change an image in my firebase storage sometimes and i want the app to keep showing the updated image,

Thank you!!

Comment: As a test, what happens if you follow the code guidelines laid out in the [Download Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) page? Specifically the Download In Memory section. i.e. loose the dispatch_async calls. Is it any faster?

Comment: only you will get the image or other details with image

Comment: @Jay it's even slower without the dispatch_async..

Comment: Well, something else is up then. We have a simple app that populates 10 or so images and it does it almost instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kingfisher library can be used to cache the image. It checks for change in the image too. After installing kingfisher lib.you can do the following:

*imageView.kf_setImageWithUrl(imageUrl)*

Comment: I installed kingfisher, be it says "value of type UIImage has no member kf_setImageWithUrl" , can you give me some code example for that please?

Comment: Use it with UIImageView  and make sure you have imported kingfisher.

Comment: i did, i just for the library i just added "pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 2.4'" and ran pod install, is it enougth?

Comment: Add  import Kingfisher to your.swift file.

Comment: i did... the same :( any suggestions please?

Comment: Use it with image view.   IMAGEVIEW.kf_ ( after you type this you will see the suggestion)